# What is the significance of a browser profiles and User Agent in UI testing?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing

I see a section called "Tweaking an existing Firefox profile" in selenium 2's documentation and wondering what would be the reason to change profiles and user agents during UI testing? Also when and where are custom profiles helpful?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**custom profiles**
Sometimes you may want to run functional tests against an application server that has fake SSL certificates. In that case Selenium will give you headache because you'll get popups to accept the certificates that selenium can't interact with. Also, Selenium will create and destroy a custom Firefox profile for each test.  i.e. You will get a popup to accept an unrecognised certificate every time and it has to be manually clicked.  Even if you select 'permanently accept' you'll continue to get the popup because your profile is not saved.

You can create your own custom profile and run your Selenium tests using this profile. If you do, you can accept all of the certificates once and Firefox will never prompt you to accept them again.

---

**user agents**
Some websites will behave differently depending on where the http requests are coming from.  For example, an iphone with safari and a pc with IE could hit the same url and get very different looking web pages.  This is controlled by the user agent.  If you need to test that iphone safari page, you can change your user agent to something like "Mobile Safari 2.2.1 – iPhone" 
If your server delivers the same content to all browsers and devices, then you probably don't have to worry about it.

http://garbuz.com/2010/07/31/running-selenium-with-custom-firefox-profile/

Answer (score 0):

You can also create custom Firefox profiles with a desired certificate keystore state to allow access into certain sites.